# How to dynamically match object values with jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I am testing an API that will return objects of customer data (id, name age etc).

These objects will have some shared data depending on my query params like location etc. with the rest being dynamic. How can I best test the returned data is what I want?

example data - Say I have searched for all customers in a particular town:

```
{
  "location": "some town",
  "data": [
    { "id": "123", "name": "Bob" },
    { "id": "234", "name": "Jane" }
  ]
}
```

Of course for each different query param town I enter, there will be different data within the `data` array and of differing lengths.

I am using Jest and am wondering what is the best way to test?

So far I have the following:

```
test('customer data location', async () => {
  const expect = require('./customer-obj.json');
  const response = await getcustomersin('some town');

  expect(response.body).toMatchObject(expected);
  expect(response.body.data).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

Where `customer-obj.json` is the JSON file:

```
{
  "location": "some town",
}
```

I used `toMatchObject` with this, but I feel that I am missing the point with not including the `data` values...

I did see `expect.arrayContaining(array)` on the official documentation, but I wouldn't know the data to include in this, as it seems to only work when you provide a subset of the overall array of data.

Comment: is it unit testing or integration testing? if it's unit testing you should mock server response so for sure will now exact value. if it's integration testing you better not validating server response and validate result UI rendered.

Answer (score 3):

You can forget about expecting the exact values and just check if the base object contains a set properties instead like so:

```
test('Contains object with location and data properties', async () => {
  const expect = require('./customer-obj.json');
  const response = await getcustomersin('some town');

  expect(typeof response.body).toBe('object');
  expect(response.body.hasOwnProperty('location')).toBe(true);
  expect(response.body.hasOwnProperty('data')).toBe(true);
});
```